# How to get data from three or more tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display distinct data between three tables. How to do this requirement.

FirstTable:

```
9999999999                     
8888888888           
7777777777
6666666666
5555555555
```

SecondTable:

```
7777777777
9999999999
```

ThirdTable:

```
8888888888
```

i want output in this format.

```
6666666666
5555555555
```

Comment: *What have you tried to achieve this result?* And what is the exact logic behind the output?

Comment: Please read on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/faq .  Show ALL table schemas.  If you are lazy, people won't help you.

Comment: still dont understand what you want to go for here, both your desired values are from "FirstTable" what exactly do you wanna do?

Comment: to get distinct data between two tables i tried but for three tables i dont know

Comment: aaaah, you want to have rows that are only present in FirstTable but NOT in SecondTable or ThirdTable?

Comment: Or it could be that he only wants to have rows that are in one of the three tables, but not more than one. So also rows that are only in SecondTable and not in FirstTable and ThirdTable.

Comment: but still this is not well phrased, provide at least some more table description (column names/types) and your best try query to achieve that.

Comment: the result doesn't show distinct data. It shows the data which is not common on any table.

Comment: Have you looked at [minus](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php). It looks to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
   SELECT T1."Col"
     FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 
       ON T1."Col" = T2."Col"
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 
       ON T1."Col" = T3."Col"
    WHERE T2."Col" IS NULL 
      AND T3."Col" IS NULL
```

Output:

```
|        COL |
--------------
| 6666666666 |
| 5555555555 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2981e/4)

Answer (score 1):

For the data you gave us, you can try this:

```
    select YourColumn from Table1
minus
    select Yourcolumn from Table2
minus
    select YourColumn from Table3
```

This however wouldn't give you entries that existed in Table 3 but not tables 1 ND 2.  I second the suggestion that you improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Select yourColumn 
from Table1 
where yourColumn  not in
   ( select yourColumn  from Table2) 
and yourColumn  not in 
  (select yourColumn  from table3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Column FROM FirstTable
WHERE Column NOT IN
    (SELECT Column from SecondTable UNION 
    SELECT Column from ThirdTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

YOUR result doesn't show distinct data. It shows the data which is not IN on any OTHER table

So you can write like this

```
    CREATE TABLE FirstTable (VALUE VARCHAR(10))

    CREATE TABLE SecondTable (VALUE VARCHAR(10))

    CREATE TABLE ThirdTable (VALUE VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES(9999999999)                     
    INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES(8888888888)
    INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES(7777777777)
    INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES(6666666666)
    INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES(5555555555)


    INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES(9999999999)                     
    INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES(7777777777)

    INSERT INTO ThirdTable VALUES(8888888888)

    SELECT a1.vALUE FROM (SELECT a.vALUE FROM FirstTable a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable b ON A.VALUE=B.VALUE
            WHERE   b.VALUE IS NULL) a1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ThirdTable c ON  A1.VALUE=C.VALUE
        WHERE c.VALUE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular inclination, I think this is a good question!

The following solution finds **`all unique values`** in three tables:

```
with middle_tab as(
select t1.id t1_id,t2.id t2_id,t3.id t3_id from tab1 t1
full outer join tab2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
full outer join tab3 t3 on t1.id=t3.id
 )

  select coalesce(t1_id,t2_id,t3_id) unique_ids from (
select t1_id,t2_id,t3_id,NVL2(t1_id,0,1)+NVL2(t2_id,0,1)+NVL2(t3_id,0,1) b
 from middle_tab)
where b>1
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle Demo!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bc10/2)**